# Windows 10 Symbolic Links

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I would like to create a symbolic link from an existing folder but MKLINK needs to create this folder but I  need to use the existing folder as it is without changing it's name. Is this possible?
Many thanks

Comment: please show us the actual mklink command you ran, and describe the actual outcome you wish to achieve.

Comment: use Hardlink Shell Extension. It's easy to use. https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: +1 for Link Shell Extension. It's an extremely handy utility.

Answer (score 1):

Mklink does not create folders, it creates links. You can name your symbolic link
the same as the target folder, but it can't be created in the same folder as the
target. Nothing about making a link requires you to change the name of the target.

Comment: Many Tx for prompt reply much appreciated. My problem is that I have an application in a PC which saves to a destination folder that I cannot change it's name or location but I want to create a link in that location to save to another location in another network location but it seems Mklink has to create the folder where the link is instead of converting the existing folder to a link

Comment: Will try the Shell Extension.

Comment: I am using for example : c:\mklink "c:\source " d:\Destination"